# Value gets truncated while running a splunk search query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

I am running a query like.
`index=1101 source=/UAT/Logs/APP_NAME*.log "Mobile Analytic Logs Mule services" | stats count by OperationName`

I am expecting the query to return a table with list of operation name between the given time frame.

But, I could see a strange behavior. The values of the column are getting truncated like below

```
"deletes
"deleteSubs
"deleteSubsc
"deleteSubscr
"deleteSubscri
"deleteSubscripti
"deleteSubscription
"deleteSubscriptionAl
"deleteSubscriptionAle
"deleteSubscriptionAlert
"g
"ge
"get
"getA
"getAle
"getAler
"getAlert
"getau
"getAuth
"getAuthst
"getCont
"getContactP
"getContactPo
"getContactPoi
```

How to fix this?

Comment: how is the field `OperationName` being extracted? What does the raw data look like?

Comment: @warren this is how it is - INFO 2023-07-31 14:53:38 Mobile Analytic Logs Mule services: : [TraceId=a4fc21e0-d6cc-46be-99de-00c@e51231e4] [[MuleRuntime].uber.40: [login. jar]. oauthflow.CPU_LITE @2c4a1675]

org. mule. runtime. core.internal. processor. LoggerMessageProcessor : 172 - OperationName="validateToken" UserId="string" StatusCode=200 ExecutionTime=1549

Answer (score 0):

Try to add such field extraction for source "/UAT/Logs/APP_NAME*.log" or sourcetype (Settings > Fields > Field extractions):

```
OperationName=\"(?<OperationName>.*?)\"
```